# What kinds of things that aren't fire (but are related to fire) could cause fire damage in a world where elemental magic exists?

Tags: energy, fire

This question arose in the comments of a question about dragons and sunlight ([How do migratory dragons avoid being blinded by sun?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/225366/how-do-migratory-dragons-avoid-being-blinded-by-sun/225389?noredirect=1#comment692960_225389)). The question is, what exactly is it that causes fire damage (in the 'magical/elemental' sense)? Is it the heat? the combustion? the flame itself?

For example, would nuclear radiation cause fire damage? Does focused sunlight cause fire damage? Does ultra-violet radiation cause fire damage? Could a heat gun cause fire damage? Would contact with red-hot steel cause fire damage? Sure, all of those are heat or heat-like and are damaging to many a great many things, but they are definitely not fire. Would they then cause *more* damage to plants or animals (or objects) that are susceptible to 'fire damage' as opposed to those that aren't?

Comment: Two problems with this question.  1. "Fire damage" is by definition caused by fire.  Without a better definition of what you are looking for, the answer is, by definition, nothing.  2.  Trying to do a damage assessment comparison of all the possible types and sizes of fire and all the heat sources that aren't fire against all possible "fire damage susceptible" plants, animals and objects is not answerable.  Please limit to a single, answerable question.

Comment: If by "fire damage" you mean "burns" then yes, the source of heat is irrelevant; only the amount of heat is important. Please clarify what you mean by "fire damage".

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 two problems with your comment. 1. if it is not answerable, you wouldn't have been able to answer it, which you did in your first point. 2. people ask pretty broad questions about fantastical nonsense on this site all the time. That's kind of the point. And 3. (as a bonus retort). I think the question is pretty clear, albeit a general one. And 4 (as an extra special surprise bonus retort!) the question is in fact  a single one. The many inquisitive sentences are meant to illustrate the general nature of the question in a clear way (hence the use of 'for example'...).

Comment: @AlexP I mean whatever the commentators in the post I referred to meant by 'fire damage'---which I guess is a kind of susceptibility to elemental magic. I was trying to avoid a lengthy discussion in the comments section by starting a new post.

Comment: This seems entirely subjective, in addition to being more about a game mechanic about grouping damage into categories than anything about building a fictional world.

Comment: @sphennings Ahem, building a fictional world is by definition a subjective endeavor, and I never mentioned games. There are many, many, examples of instances in fantasy literature wherein things are susceptible to certain types of magical/elemental forces. The Discworld books are a well-known example of a fictional world in which the interaction between Earthly physics and subjective imaginings of elemental and magical forces is explored/played with. I fail to see how this question is not, therefor, in line with the subject matter on this forum.

Comment: Also, I thought this SE was about fun stuff. If I want to be 'objectively precise' I go to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Fire causes damage by heating up atoms and combining them with oxygen, breaking whatever bonds they had before. If you burn one molecule of sugar for example, meaning that you react it with oxygen, you get carbon dioxide and water after the reaction, or C12H22O11 (sucrose) + 12 O2 (molecular oxygen) —> 12 CO2 (carbon dioxide) + 11 H2O (water). But sugar doesn't just react with oxygen sitting on a table, you need a heat source to give the molecules enough kinetic energy to break their chemical bonds and form new ones. Once the reaction takes place it makes more heat, which keeps the fire going as long as there's more fuel and oxygen around. Remember the fire triangle? Fuel + Oxygen + Heat = fire, and if you take away any of those and the fire goes out.

Once the reaction takes place, it's no longer sugar. Same thing with anything else. Once you mix it with oxygen, it's no longer the first thing anymore.

Although what I described above is what happens with regular old fire (rapid exothermic self-perpetuating oxidization), you could combine your fuel (sugar or otherwise) with something other than oxygen and have a different kind of reaction. Oxidization is just a pretty common reaction on Earth because we have this somewhat volatile little molecule all over the place with a double bond just looking for trouble.

There are other ways to break chemical bonds that are not self perpetuating. You could shoot the thing with UV rays, gamma rays, beta radiation, flood it with ions, electrolysis, depending on the target and the context. Good luck!

Comment: I've edited the original post in an attempt to clarify. I understand combustion in terms of a chemical reaction catalyzed by heat. The question is more to do with 'fire damage' in the sense of elemental magic, not the physical effects of different types of burning.